# Cancel operation in setTimeout if condition changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an operation that is to be performed after a time interval if a condition is true. I'm doing something like this

```
if($scope.goToNextPage==true){
    setTimeout(() => {
        $scope.location.path('nextPage');
    },4000)       
}
```

However, if `$scope.goToNextPage` changes within this duration, I need to stop this from being executed. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can another condition before executing that statement like

```
if ($scope.goToNextPage) { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (!$scope.goToNextPage) {
            return false;
        }
        $scope.location.path('nextPage');
    }, 4000)
}
```

Also no need to check with `==` , you can directly add variable as it is boolean

Answer (score 0):

Change the goToNextPage to false when stop executes. Then check again as below,

```
if($scope.goToNextPage==true){
    setTimeout(() => {
        if($scope.goToNextPage){
            $scope.location.path('nextPage');
        }  
    },4000)       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$timeout` service by angularjs. It returns promise which can be cancelled by $timeout.cancel method. [Ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)